# Automatic reset when click another link

Tags: javascript, html, css

The Code Below is when you click a certain div. the hidden item will show up and change the css to display block. and i have multiple menu or option what im trying to do is when you click a certein div. and you click another one. **the first one close automatically** this is the indiciator `<?php the_title(); ?>` or id of the div.

Html

```
    <a id="mylink" class="career-en blue" href="javascript:showhide('<?php the_title(); ?>')">

                <div class="Career-entry" >

                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col-md-5ths col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
                         <?php the_field( 'position' ); ?>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-5ths col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
                         <?php the_field( 'brandsubsidiary' ); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-5ths col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
                         <?php the_field( 'work_location' ); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-5ths col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
                         <?php the_field( 'date_posted' ); ?>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-5ths col-sm-6  col-xs-12">
                         <?php the_field( 'aplication_dead_line_' ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                </a>



          <div class="career-content" id="<?php the_title(); ?>" style="display:none;">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h6> <i> Position Summary: </i></h6>

                     <?php the_field( 'position_summary' ); ?>

                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                         <h6> <i> Requirments: </i></h6>


                               <?php  if( have_rows('requirments') ):?>

                                    <?php    while ( have_rows('requirments') ) : the_row(); ?>

                                        <p class="reqs"> - <?php the_sub_field('para'); ?> </p>

                                      <?php  endwhile; else : ?>

                                <?php endif;  ?>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h6> <i>Major Duties & Responsibilities: </i></h6>

                         <?php  if( have_rows('major') ):?>

                                    <?php    while ( have_rows('major') ) : the_row(); ?>

                                            <p class="reqs"> - <?php the_sub_field('para'); ?> </p>

                                          <?php  endwhile; else : ?>

                                    <?php endif;  ?>  

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h6> <i> Submit yoru resume: </i></h6>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


                            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12">
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="112" title="Career"]' ); ?>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>



               <hr class="career-hr"> 
    <?php if ($x == 2) { echo '<div class="blog_box clear"></div>'; $x = -1; } $x++; ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </div>
```

Css

```
.red{
    background-color: #e7f2ca;
    display: block;
}
```

JS

```
         <script>
         function showhide(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
         } 
        </script>
        <script> 
        $('a#mylink').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
        });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class ex. 'autohide' to all divs you want to autohide. Then:

```
 $('.autohide').click(function(){
        $('.autohide').hide();
        $(this).show();
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak your code a bit, just use a variable to keep track of currently open section.

```
var current_open_section;

function showhide(id){

   //hide open section first
   if(current_open_section){
       current_open_section.style.display = 'none';
   }
   //let the selected section be current open section
   current_open_section = document.getElementById(id);

  //show current open section
  current_open_section.style.display = 'block';

}
```